# pandas.tocsv() format issue (?) resulting in error when using psycopg2 copy_from

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

Overview:
I have a function in an external file that returns a dataframe that I then save to a csv with:

```
df.to_csv('filepath.csv', na_rep="0", index=False)
```

I then try to import the csv into a postgres table using the pyscopg2 function copy_from:

```
try:
    connect = psycopg2.connect(database = "", user = "", password = "", host = "", port = "")  
except:
    print("Could not connect to database")
cursor = connect.cursor()
with open("filepath", 'r') as open_csv:
    next(open_csv)
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(open_csv, sep=",")
        connect.commit()
        print("Copy Complete")
    except:
        print("Copy Error")
    cursor.close()
```

This results in a copy error exception in the code above (so no real detail) but there are some weird caveats:

For some reason, if I open the csv in libre office and manually save it as a text csv and then run just the above psycopg2 copy_from process, the copy works and there are no issues. So for whatever reason, in the eyes of psycopg2 copy_from, something is off with the to.csv() write that gets fixed if I just manually save the file. Manually saving the csv does not result in any visual changes so what is happening here?

Also, the above psycopg2 code snippet works without error in another file in which all dataframe manipulation is contained within the single file where the to.csv() is completed. So something about returning a dataframe from a function in an external file is off?

Fwiw, when debugging, the issue came up on the .copy_from() line so the issue has something to do with csv formatting and I cannot figure it out. I found a workaround with sqlalchemy but would like to know what I am missing here instead of ignoring the problem.

In the postgres error log, the error is: "invalid input syntax for type integer: "-1.0". This error is occurring in the last column of my table where the value is set as an INT and in the csv, the value is -1 but it is being interpreted as -1.0. Where I am confused is that if I use a COPY query to directly input the csv file into postgres, it does not have a problem. Why does it interpret the value as -1.0 through psycopg2 but not directly in postgres?

This is my first post so if more detail is needed let me know - thanks in advance for the help

Comment: And the error message is what? Add as update to your question.

Comment: The error is just the exception in the code snippet "Copy Error" - I clarified it but it does not apply any additional information unfortunately

Comment: If you didn't swallow the exception message it would be useful. Or look in the Postgresql log and see what it is? In any case without the error message this is going nowhere.

Comment: Added the postgres error message - it is nvalid input syntax for type integer: "-1.0" but it only has this error with the psycopg2 code. If I take the same csv file that does not work with the psycopg2 code and input it into the database with a COPY query, there is no issue

Comment: It is a casting problem: `select  -1.0::integer; -1, select  '-1.0'::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "-1.0"`.  In the `psycopg2` code the value is coming in as text.

Comment: If I open the csv file and just manually save it (making no changes), psycopg2 has no errors. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Open it LibreOffice as you state in your question or open it in some other program? If in LibreOffice I could see where it might change a string of `'-1.0'` to an integer.

Comment: I should have been clearer. CSV is text format so everything is going to come via COPY as text. The difference is whether it is quoted e.g. '-1.0' or as -1.0. I could see LibreOffice removing the quotes on save.

Comment: Appreciate the help - new to programming so my troubleshooting skill is lacking. this was a learning experience, thanks.

Comment: So what did you find out?

Comment: The column in question was calculated as 1 or -1 depending on other values in the row. Despite being ints, the column type in python was actually float32 so when the csv was saved, the underlying value was 1.0/-1.0 even though it visually appeared as 1/-1 in LibreOffice Calc and a print of the df. After saving the file, those float values became 1/-1 (losing the decimal) allowing the upload to proceed seamlessly since the postgresql table column was designated as INT.

Comment: Hmm, some digging found this [Integer NA](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na). Do you have `NaN` values in the data frame? If so it seems Pandas will convert the entire column into floats.

Comment: Oh interesting, yes I did. That completes the picture then. What made you think to look for that?

Comment: Process of elimination narrowed it down to Pandas. From there I searched on 'pandas to_csv integers as floats'. That led me to the FAQ entry.